# Azure Functions v3 no longer auto-tracking dependencies after adding injected TelemetryConfiguration

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights, asp.net-core-3.1

Currently have an azure function v3 in .netcore 3.1 with the following host.json

```html
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": false,
        "excludedTypes": "Exception"
      },
      "dependencyTrackingOptions": {
        "enableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation": true
      }
    },
    "logLevel": {
      "Function": "Information",
      "Host.Aggregator": "Information",
      "Host.Results": "Information",
      "default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

Things were working fine with SQL dependencies being auto tracked in app insights.  Needing to also track redis calls I've added telemetryClient via dependency injection as recommended with

`telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(telemetryConfiguration);`

After doing this, however, I am only receiving dependency calls I manually write via telemetry client and no longer getting the default SQL calls.

I've tried manually creating a DependencyCollector.DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule
and initializing it with the injected telemetryConfiguration and setting
`EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation = true` , but although this does enable SQL tracing, it does not bind it to the calling context.

Has anyone run into this issue before or have any advice in how to properly implement custom telemetry while also maintaining default dependency tracking?

Comment: You can refer to similar GitHub issues: [App Insights does not collect SQL dependencies out of the box](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1613#issuecomment-802899247), [ITelemetryProcessor does not appear to be supported in Function Apps](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3741#issuecomment-645964338) and [Injecting TelemetryConfiguration no longer works after updating from v3-Preview to v3](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5353#issuecomment-578768524)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgraded Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights to same version as Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions and it worked.