# Directly referencing ApplicationInsights in Azure Functions loses SQL dependency tracking

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I have an Azure Functions v3 project running .NET Core 3.1 configured with Application Insights that does not track SQL dependencies. I can see requests, exceptions, and traces, but SQL dependencies don't show up.

I'm using an internal NuGet package for a class that that wraps TelemetryClient for things like logging custom events and metrics.

```cs
 internal class ApplicationInsightsTelemetryService: ITelemetryService
    {
        private readonly TelemetryClient _telemetryClient;

        public ApplicationInsightsTelemetryService(TelemetryClient telemetryClient)
        {
            _telemetryClient = telemetryClient;
        }

        public void LogEvent(string eventName, Dictionary<string, string> data = null)
        {
            _telemetryClient.TrackEvent(eventName, data);
        }

        public void LogMetric(string metricName, double value)
        {
            var metric = _telemetryClient.GetMetric(metricName);
            metric.TrackValue(value);
        }
    }
```

Removing this library and stubbing out the wrapper fixes the problem. SQL queries are logged as expected. I tried ruling out this library, so I rewrote the wrapper class, but it needs a reference to the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights` package. The moment I add that reference, I lose SQL query tracking.

I even tried installing v2.20.0 (which is deprecated) as that seems to be what version the SDK is pulling in, but that doesn't work.

I've also tried other things mentioned in Stack Overflow, like adding `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService`, but in the end they all reference `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights` so we run into this again.

I've already spent a day trying to resolve this. Is this a package mismatch issue? How can I tell it to use the version that the SDK is already using? I've set a breakpoint in the Startup and can see that `TelemetryClient` is being added, I just need to use it!

Answer (score 0):

Of course as soon as I decide to ask Stack Overflow, I figure it out (thanks in no small part to the answers on [Azure Functions v3 no longer auto-tracking dependencies after adding injected TelemetryConfiguration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70299686/azure-functions-v3-no-longer-auto-tracking-dependencies-after-adding-injected-te)).

This was related to the `System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource` issue referenced [here](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1613). Removing the DLL from the bin folder worked. I checked the NuGet versions of `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights` and found the last one that didn't require a higher version of `System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource`, which turns out to be `2.15.0`. I'm hopeful that once we're able to upgrade to .NET 6, we won't have to do this.